# Verifying calls with ref parameters using Moq

Tags: moq, ref, verify

How can I verify that the "CallWithRef" method was called using Moq?

```
public interface ITest
{
    void CallWithoutRef(string value, List<string> errors);
    void CallWithRef(string value, ref List<string> errors);
}

public class Foo
{
    private ITest testInterface;

    public Foo(ITest testInterface)
    {
        this.testInterface = testInterface;
    }

    public void DoStuff(string value)
    {
        var errorList = new List<string>();
        testInterface.CallWithoutRef(value, errorList);
        testInterface.CallWithRef(value, ref errorList);
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void VerifyTestInterfaceCalls()
{
    var expectedValue = Path.GetRandomFileName();
    var mockTestInterface = new Mock<ITest>();
    var foo = new Foo(mockTestInterface.Object);

    foo.DoStuff(expectedValue);
    mockTestInterface.Verify(x => x.CallWithoutRef(expectedValue, It.IsAny<List<string>>()));

    // Test fails here:
    var errorList = It.IsAny<List<string>>();
    mockTestInterface.Verify(x => x.CallWithRef(expectedValue, ref errorList));
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has changed for the better in Moq 4.8.0, see the other answer here for details on `It.Ref`!

---

Calls to `Verify` in Moq perform a strict equality check for `ref` arguments.  When the argument is a reference type (like in your example), the [argument matcher that Moq uses](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/Matchers/RefMatcher.cs) succeeds only if the actual and expected values are the *same reference*.  This is because it uses `object.ReferenceEquals(expected, actual)` to verify equality.

This behavior is mentioned (although it could be a little more thorough) in the [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart):

```
// ref arguments
var instance = new Bar();
// Only matches if the ref argument to the invocation is the same instance
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Submit(ref instance)).Returns(true);
```

In your example, `It.IsAny<List<string>>()` actually returns `default(T)` in the end, so you're comparing `null` to the new instance of a `List<string>` created in `DoStuff`, which according to the matcher's implementation will fail.

This is obviously a toy example so I can't suggest what you should do, but if you modify `DoStuff` to accept the list rather than create its own, you could test it like this:

```
var errorList = It.IsAny<List<string>>(); 
// var errorList = new List<string>();   // also works

foo.DoStuff(expectedValue, errorList);

mockTestInterface.Verify(x => x.CallWithoutRef(expectedValue, It.IsAny<List<string>>()));
mockTestInterface.Verify(x => x.CallWithRef(expectedValue, ref errorList));
```

Comment: if you are looking at this answer and you have v4.8.0+ don't be like me and not notice the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/49537043/435706 by @Spencer-Sutton

Comment: Thanks @ShereefMarzouk, I added some text to point to the other answer.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

As of version 4.8.0 this is now possible using Moq. Here's the link: https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/479

You would pass errorList in like this

```
ref It.Ref<List<string>>.IsAny
```

Comment: P.S. If you are using the `mockedBla.Protected()` and `using moq.Protected;` you should use `ItExpr` instead of `It`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.